# How to find details about very first block mined for any crypto?

Tags: blockchain, genesis-block

Hi is there any resource or site where we can see details of the very first block mined like its time-stamp and other details . I have been asking around in groups for last 3 days no answer .

I did find some details about bitcoin but would like to find for other crypto coins too.[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have an altcoin's node software and that software is based off of Bitcoin Core, then you can use the following RPC commands to get information about the genesis block:

```
getblockhash 0
```

This will get you the hash of the genesis block. Take that hash and do

```
getblock <hash>
```

This will give you all of the information about the genesis block.